# How to execute many circuits on an IBMQ backend?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I attempted to `execute` a list of $3200$ `QuantumCircuit`s in Qiskit, each with the `max_shots` of $8096$ as follows:

```
ibmq_manhattan = provider.get_backend('ibmq_manhattan')
job = execute(all_qc, backend=ibmq_manhattan, shots=8096)
job_monitor(job)
```

and got the following response:

> Job Status: job has been cancelled

Furthermore, I successfully performed the exact same execution locally using the Aer `qasm_simulator`. Presumably this is because there is a runtime timeout on the IBMQ backend device which is triggered as one might expect for such a large list. Is this correct? and if so how can I bypass this limitation?

This is a summary of the job on IBMQ:
[image: job summary on IBMQ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more circuits than what the backend allows, consider using [IBMQJobManager](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.IBMQJobManager.html#qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.IBMQJobManager), which will divide the circuits and collect results for you.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the backend `max_experiments` property. The amount of circuits in a job ( `len(all_qc)`) should be smaller than that.

For example, in `ibmq_16_melbourne`:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ

IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q')
device = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
device.configuration().max_experiments
```

```
75
```

Comment: thanks for that, ibmq_manhattan has a limit of 900, however executing a single circuit took ~40s, so if I were to execute 900 then that would take about ~10 hours. I don't mind waiting, but does the backend not have an execution timeout?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... just make sure you have your job id to retrieve your result.

Comment: will do, thanks :)